# Flex-grow does not change the state of an element

Tags: css, flexbox

Why does flex-grow: 1 not work here? I want the elements to share the whole space and there are no spaces between them. They should be navigation buttons to which you can add one if you need one more. If possible please use flex-box, I would like to understand it.

http://jsfiddle.net/vqL95o0s/1/

**CSS**

```
header{
    background-color: #1D3557;
    height: 300px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

ul.navlist {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 0;
  }


a.button {
    height: 75px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
        <header style="background-image: url('img/headerStripes.png')">
            <img src="img/webdev_logo.png" alt="Logo">
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 3</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 5</a></li>
                <li><a class="button active">Example 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
```

The boxes stayed in one place at a distance, but did not get any bigger.

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer. Read that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, you are **applying [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property on "a element"**. You should apply the flex-grow on the direct child of flexbox that is **li items**. Here is the updated code:-

```css
header{
    background-color: #1D3557;
    height: 300px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

ul.navlist {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 0;
  }

ul.navlist > li:nth-child(1){
  flex-grow: 1;
}

a.button {
    height: 75px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
        <header style="background-image: url('img/headerStripes.png')">
            <img src="img/webdev_logo.png" alt="Logo">
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 3</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 5</a></li>
                <li><a class="button active">Example 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
```

Here I applied **flex-grow to the first li item**.

Comment: stupid mistake on my part, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the flex-grow property for the li elements as they are the direct children of the navlist in which you want them to grow.

```css
header{
    background-color: #1D3557;
    height: 300px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

ul.navlist {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    list-style-type: none;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 0;
  }

.navlist li{
  flex-grow:1;
}

a.button {
    height: 75px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
        <header style="background-image: url('img/headerStripes.png')">
            <img src="img/webdev_logo.png" alt="Logo">
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 3</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="#">Example 5</a></li>
                <li><a class="button active">Example 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You `a` tag is inside the `li` element. This one should fill the space :

```
li {
    flex:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dL7nz9xw/

And you don't need the `flex-grow: 1;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

> The alignment is done after the lengths and auto margins are applied,
> meaning that, if in a Flexbox layout there is at least one flexible
> element, with flex-grow different from 0, it will have no effect as
> there won't be any available space.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `justify-content: space-between` on your `.navlist` (or set it back to `normal`) and set the `flex-grow: 1;` on your `li` elements rather than your anchors. Your `a` are not flex items because they are not the direct children of your `ul`. Hope it helps.